# Can I connect directly a 3.7V 18650 li-ion battery to a mobile (cellphone)?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, cellphone, mobile

If I remove the 3.7V battery from my mobile, is it possible to connect to the battery +/- terminals a 3.7V li-ion 18650 battery?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to the current of your battery lithium 18650, if you overdischarge the battery, it may lead to the venting or exploding of your battery and damage your phone.